# ASP.NET Server.HtmlEncode Won't Encode €

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-encode

I know that the EURO currency symbol (€) is encoded as `&euro;` in HTML, but the `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("€")` doesn't encode it at all. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: @Daniel I'd downvote your comment for being ignorant (even if you're joking). Unfortunately I can't.

Comment: I wasn't being ignorant. I thought I was being irreverant and slightly obnoxious, but if I was being ignorant then I am ignorant of what I was being ignorant about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` only encodes characters that are "reserved" in HTML.  For that list, see the first table on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp.

In other words, only those characters that can conflict with the basic structre of HTML (e.g. <, >, ", etc).  No other characters *must* be encoded as long as the encoding of the transmitted bytes is identified correctly (e.g. by using and declaring UTF-8).

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? I'm using HtmlEncode, and it's encoding degree symbols into &#176;, but it isn't encoding trademark symbols. I understand what you're saying, but it seems to apply the choice of coding inconsistently. I don't think that degree symbols are reserved in HTML.

Comment: I may have been wrong when I wrote the answer 2.5 years ago, or ASP.NET may have been changed. I've not been using ASP.NET recently so can't confirm or deny either possibility. If you have the time, I encourage you to research and write here a more accurate and up-to-date answer.